# Modx TinyMCE HTML formatting

Tags: tinymce, modx

I'm currently building a site that allows previewing photos and videos using Shadowbox.  I'm also using the jQuery Tools Scrollable tool to allows the thumbnails to be scrolled.  I'm using ModX as the CMS.

I want whoever edits the page to be able to use TinyMCE as the editor, this has been OK for the photos but for the videos I want a description for each video too.  I need the code to be in the following format as each of the elements for a video need to be wrapped in a div for the scrollable to work properly.

```
<div>
   <a href="video_preview/stupid girl.flv"><img src="images/vid.gif" alt="video 1" title="Stupid Girl" /></a>
   <h4>STUPID GIRL</h4>
   <p>Garbage perform classic hit Stupid Girl</p>
</div>
<div>
   <a href="video_preview/rehearsals.flv"><img src="images/rehearsals.jpg" alt="video 2" title="Rehearsals" /></a>
   <h4>REHEARSALS</h4>
   <p>Garbage back stage and at rehearsals</p>
</div>
```

Here there are 2 videos put I want to allow any number of videos to be entered.  At the moment I can't get TinyMCE to generate code in this format.  How do I go about doing this or is there a different way I should be looking at this.  At the moment the above code section is contained within it's own Chunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this in the wrong manner.

Create a new folder called Videos
The documents in Videos don't need to show in menu etc. Assign the documents in Videos a template in this case "videos-template"

Create template variables for that template for the following items: Movie-file, title, description.

Use the HTML you have there in a chunk, in this case "video-chunk" ie.

```
    <div>
   <a href="[*Movie-file*]"><img src="images/vid.gif" alt="video 1" title="Stupid Girl" /></a>
   <h4>[*title*]</h4>
   <p>[*description*]</p>
</div>
```

Then in a chunk use Ditto to interate through your "videos" folder with the above chunk as the template ie.

```
[!Ditto? &parents=`183`&orderBy=`createdon ASC` &display=`5`
  &total=`5` &tpl=`video-chunk`!]
```

Let me know if that makes sense but in my mind you should certainly be tackling it in a manner similar to this.

This way when the user wants to add new videos they simply create a new document in the videos folder and set the template variables.

Comment: I guess should say why I think this method is better...

By using this approach the users can't screw up the HTML which in my experience is inevitable if they have access to do so.

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I was looking for an iterative solution but pretty new to modx.  Makes perfect sense.

Comment: I agree, removing access to the HTML is most important.

Comment: A very good structured answer. 

@cabonara - I would probably take this as the accepted answer